# How do I limit the number of items shown from an Array?

Tags: swiftui

I have this code :

```
ForEach(backgroundImages.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                        ZStack {
        
                            Image(backgroundImages[i])
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
            
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .strokeBorder(LinearGradient(colors: [Color.white.opacity(0.3), Color.white.opacity(0), Color.white.opacity(0.3)], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), lineWidth: 1)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .onTapGesture{self.feedback()}
                          
                        }
                        .onTapGesture { selectedBackground = i }
                    }
```

I'd like to only pick the first 20 items. The array has over 50.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prefix(_ maxLength:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/prefix(_:)) to get a subsequence:

```swift
ForEach(backgroundImages.indices.prefix(20, id: \.self) { i in
    // ...
}
```